# I am using an IF statement in VBA to compare a calculated date to the dates in a table. I however keep getting the #NAME? error

Tags: excel, vba, date

'A year ago from current date
Dim LastYear As Date

LastYear = Now() - 365

Range("Class[Date_Check]").Formula = "= IF(Class[FAILDATE]< LastYear),""Bad"",""Good"")"

Comment: "LastYear" is not something the formula parser knows anything about.  Shouldn't it be called "Yesterday" though?

Comment: **LastYear** is a variable. When you put it between quotes it becomes a **String** Is this what you are trying? `Range("Class[Date_Check]").Formula = "= IF(Class[FAILDATE]< " & LastYear & "),""Bad"",""Good"")"`

Comment: Siddharth you're right. LastYear is a date though. I'm trying to compare the values in FAILDATE column.

Comment: LastYear is basically current date minus 1 year

Comment: @chewBuka: This is what you intended to be, but in fact it is exactly what Tim Williams suggested... `Now` returns the actual time. Using `-1` you decrease it with one day.

Comment: @FaneDuru it is meant to be -365 my apologies. But even with the chnage the code still shows #NAME?

Comment: Which part of the code? I must confess that I never used `Class[FAILDATE]`. I even do not know anything about such a construction. If `FAILDATE` is a  named range, why don't you use as it is? Without any class or `[]`? What do you want to accomplish, in fact? What the Class in front of the named range wants to do?

Comment: If `Date_Check` is a range where you need to place a formula to compare the previous year with the `FAILDATE` (name range) why do no try something like that, without previously defining LastYear? `[Date_Check].Formula = "=If(YEAR(FAILDATE)<YEAR(TODAY() - 365),""Good"",""Bad"")"`. Didn't it work as you need?